# Aurelia binding behavior with html 5 datalist

Tags: aurelia

Please, in this gist ( https://gist.run/?id=549282ece087785a3b7f6eb9c9d6a6d4 ), selectedValue shouldn't have the value of "option json object"?
It seems that binding with model.bind on the option html element inside of a datalist element, does not work in the same way as when inside of a select element.
Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The binding system has no special logic for input+datalist. It's easy to add with a `input.delegate` binding:

https://gist.run/?id=dc040a0087aa8a99a5f2dc0fc721dca3

**app.html**

```html
<template>
  <input type="text" list="myDatalist" input.delegate="selectedValue = findOption($event.target.value)" />
  <datalist id="myDatalist">
    <option repeat.for="option of options">${option.name}</option>
  </datalist>

  <pre style="margin-top: 100px"><code>${selectedValue}</code></pre>
</template>
```

**app.js**

```js
export class App {
  selectedValue = null;
  options = [ { id: 1, name: 'one' }, { id: 2, name: 'two' } ];
  findOption = value => this.options.find(x => x.name === value);
}
```

Users are free to type in whatever they want, even things that don't match a suggestion in the datalist so you'll need to plan for that.

Comment: Thank you, Jeremy. But there is no way I can show one thing and bind the model with another? In the application we are building, the 'name' property in question can be sometimes big, so I would like to avoid a search by matching names...I'm starting to consider that the datalist may not be the appropriate element to use, in our case...

Comment: In my example, `selectedValue` is assigned an object (one of the options). You will need to come up with a mechanism for mapping the input's value (a string) to a particular option object. I created a function that found the option with the matching name in my example. There's no way around this that I know of. The datalist element doesn't raise any events and the input element's input/change events don't tell you when a datalist option was selected vs standard data entry.